# Xcode crash on maximized window

Tags: xcode, crash, maximize

I'm having issues with Xcode 6.1.1 where it is crashing when maximized and *Build and Run* pressed. The whole thing bombs-out with no error dialog report/restart option.

Consequently I have to run Xcode just under 'full screen'.

Anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround?

This is running with Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: I'm having sort of the same issue. When I upgraded to 10.10.2 ... now xCode crashes every time I try to open it.

Comment: Does this happen when you press cmd-R as well? Or just when you press the run button?

Comment: No it seems to work OK with CMD-R. What I'm suspicious of is the Run button (>) is in exactly the same position as the red close button (x) when the toolbar is shown if you move the mouse to the top of the screen. I'm thinking it's getting a close-window message as xcode doesn't actually crash, it just closes my project.

Comment: I'm pleased to say this now works without crashing on xCode 6.3